# Asp.net session time is too short

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am creating webforms with asp.net. Website is working based session authority. But i have problem from session timeouts. for example when i logged in to my system after 4-5 minutes session will expire. I tried everything to make session timeout longer. Here is something ;

I changed plesk panel session timeout to 2000;

in web.config file

```
<sessionState timeout="120"></sessionState>
```

my login page

```
Session["user_id"] = "12313";
Session["username"] = "john doe";
Session.Timeout = 2000;
```

i am using these codes for control session. in my default.aspx page

```
if(Session["user_id"] != null)
{
Response.Write("you are logged");
}
else
{
Response.Write("Please sign in");
}
```

Why my session expires in 4-5 minutes?

Comment: Are you sure you are not disposing your `Session`?

Comment: Do you have session state set in IIS too? and which IIS ver you are on?

Comment: @Nitin i am using plesk panel from my hosting provider. Not on my windows IIS

Comment: @DominikS yes i am sure about this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following code block in your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: i added your code into my web.config file. now in google chrome it is working. But in yandex browser not. I think i should prefer chrome :)

Comment: I don't have much idea about yandex browser. i have to check for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following links might help resolving the issue. 
[Managing Session TimeOut using Web.Config](http://forums.asp.net/t/1143744.aspx?Managing%20Session%20TimeOut%20using%20Web%20Config)

[Weird Timeouts with custom ASP.NET FormsAuthentication](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdTimeoutsWithCustomASPNETFormsAuthentication.aspx)